# Mysql count records grouped by ID in multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm developing an application integrated with facebook. This application can be embedded in FB page as tab app.

Using FB SDK feeds of page will be stored in **Feeds** table.
Page fans will may have liked and commented on feeds posted by page.
Users' likes store in **Like** Table and users' comments store in **Comment** table

I want to get total count ( Likes count + comment count) of each users'.

SQL Fiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ecb37/10/0

Table : **Feeds**

```
| ID |                         POST_ID |
|----|---------------------------------|
| 56 | 150348635024244_795407097185058 |
| 55 | 150348635024244_795410940518007 |
| 54 | 150348635024244_795414953850939 |
| 53 | 150348635024244_797424133650021 |
| 52 | 150348635024244_797455793646855 |
| 51 | 150348635024244_798997120159389 |
| 50 | 150348635024244_798997946825973 |
```

Table : **Likes**

```
SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) FROM likes GROUP by user_id

|          USER_ID | LIKECOUNT |
|------------------|-----------|
|  913403225356462 |         4 |
|  150348635024244 |         3 |
|  356139014550882 |         2 |
|  753274941400012 |         2 |
| 1559751687580867 |         1 |
```

Table : **Comments**

```
SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) FROM comments GROUP by user_id

|         USER_ID | COMMENTSCOUNT |
|-----------------|---------------|
| 150348635024244 |             2 |
| 356139014550882 |             2 |
| 913403225356462 |             2 |
```

---

Result should be like this

```
| POINTS | LIKESCOUNT | COMMENTSCOUNT |         USER_ID |
|--------|------------|---------------|-----------------|
|      6 |          4 |             2 | 913403225356462 |
|      5 |          3 |             2 | 150348635024244 |
|      4 |          2 |             2 | 356139014550882 |
|      2 |          2 |             0 | 753274941400012 |
|      1 |          1 |             0 |1559751687580867 |
```

I tried this query. but count of each user's is wrong

```
SELECT COUNT(likes.user_id)+COUNT(comments.user_id) as points, likes.user_id FROM `likes` 
LEFT JOIN comments ON likes.user_id = comments.user_id 
LEFT JOIN feeds ON likes.post_id = feeds.post_id 
WHERE likes.post_id LIKE '153548635024244%' 
GROUP BY likes.user_id 
ORDER BY points DESC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two queries are unrelated and a join is useless. Use a UNION ALL:

```
SELECT user_id, sum(n) from (
    SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) n FROM likes GROUP by user_id
    UNION ALL
    SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) FROM comments GROUP by user_id
) x
GROUP BY user_id
```

UNION ALL is needed instead of just UNION, because UNION removes duplicates and would cause incorrect results for the edge case of the two subqueries yielding the same counts.

Answer (score 0):

The simple way to get what you want is to use `count(distinct)`.  But that will likely have lousy performance.  Instead, use correlated subqueries:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) +
       (select COUNT(c.user_id) from comments c where c.user_id = l.user_id)
       ) as points, l.user_id
FROM likes l
WHERE l.post_id LIKE '153548635024244%' 
GROUP BY l.user_id 
ORDER BY points DESC;
```

I'm not sure what the `feeds` table is for.  However, you version of the query creates a cartesian product between the different tables.  If you have a lot of activity for a given user, that would be very bad for performance.

Comment: thank you very much for the quick reply. feed table is used to filter most recent posts. Let me try ur query